# How to delete an object based on a specific property that is nil

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have three models, a parent, child, grandchild.  I have been able to save and link the data correctly.  Now I would like to be able to delete the child and grandchild objects, when I delete the parent.

The parent has a property of the child and the child has a property of the grandchild.

Example:

```
class Parent: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    var child = List<Child>
}

class Child: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var parent: Parent?
    var grandChild = List<GrandChild>
}

class GrandChild: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var child: Child?
}
```

(This is not my actual code, so if I messed up on anything here please disregard any errors.)

What I would like to do is to delete the parent, which would make the property of 'parent' in the Child object nil.  Then I would like to delete the child object if it's parent property is nil.  Then do the same for the grandChild.  In other words do a cascading deletion of objects.

So, something like:

if the parent property of Object: Child is nil, then delete the Object.

This seems like a simple problem to solve but I can't find a lot of examples of nested data models from Realm on these boards, or I am not asking the questions in the right way to find them.

Comment: I read about, Support for cascading deletes #1104.  I'm looking for a workaround until the feature is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for cascading deletes in Realm currently, so you have to manually remove child instances. You can use `LinkingObjects` to remove all children before deleting the parent or just query all child instances where `parent == nil` after parent is deleted and delete them. See more possible solutions here: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1186

Comment: Your second suggestions of finding the object where the parent is nil is what I am looking for,  I just can't find any examples of code that would do that.  I'm not as familiar with predicates as I should be.  Would you please provide a code example?

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly.  It was my inexperience in working with Realm filtering that was the problem.  All I did was let countertopsToBeDeleted = realm.objects(Countertop.self).filter("room == nil")
        
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(countertopsToBeDeleted)